# Compact framework - cannot read directory contents - winioerror

Tags: .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have many Windows CE 5 devices in the field, running our software.

Part of their duty is to zip up some directories, and send to the server.

On about 3 (of several hundred) devices, I get this error, consistently, when trying to zip up a directory.  The zipping process involves descending through every subdirectory and adding the files.

```
System.IO.IOException: IOException
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String fullPath, Boolean file)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetDirectories(String path, String searchPattern)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(String path, String searchPattern)
```

This happens every time on this device - not random.

Copying the directory contents to my development device, and running the same (on the same directory contents) does NOT cause the error.   I do not have the actual device to debug interactively.

Of course, this WinIOError is not very useful in terms of determining actual cause. Can anyone give me any hints as to what could cause the CF to fail so spectacularly when just trying to read the directory contents?

As you can see below, common things like the directory no longer existing are handled by a specific exception to that effect - not the generic WinIOError.

Many thanks for any clues.

Below is the disassembled function:

```
// System.IO.Directory
    internal static string[] InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(string fullPath, bool file)
    {
      char c = fullPath[fullPath.Length - 1];
      if (c == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar || c == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar || c == Path.VolumeSeparatorChar)
      {
        fullPath += '*';
      }
      string[] array = new string[10];
      int num = 0;
      HostNative.FIND_DATA fIND_DATA = new HostNative.FIND_DATA();
      if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)))
      {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();
      }
      int handle;
      int num2 = PAL.File_OpenAndReadDir(fullPath, out handle, fIND_DATA);
      if (num2 != 0)
      {
        if (num2 == -2147479552 || num2 == -2147479545)
        {
          return new string[0];
        }
        __Error.WinIOError(num2, Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath));
      }
      int num3 = 0;
      do
      {
        bool flag;
        if (file)
        {
          flag = (0 == (fIND_DATA.dwFileAttributes & 16));
        }
        else
        {
          flag = (0 != (fIND_DATA.dwFileAttributes & 16));
          if (flag && (fIND_DATA.cFileName.Equals(".") || fIND_DATA.cFileName.Equals("..")))
          {
            flag = false;
          }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
          num3++;
          if (num == array.Length)
          {
            string[] array2 = new string[array.Length * 2];
            Array.Copy(array, 0, array2, 0, num);
            array = array2;
          }
          array[num++] = fIND_DATA.cFileName;
        }
        num2 = PAL.File_ReadDir(handle, fIND_DATA);
      }
      while (num2 == 0);
      PAL.File_CloseDir(handle);
      if (num2 != 0 && num2 != -2147479545)
      {
        __Error.WinIOError(num2, Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath));
      }
      if (!file && num3 == 1 && (fIND_DATA.dwFileAttributes & 16) != 0)
      {
        return new string[]
        {
          fIND_DATA.cFileName
        };
      }
      if (num == array.Length)
      {
        return array;
      }
      string[] array3 = new string[num];
      Array.Copy(array, 0, array3, 0, num);
      return array3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physically broken storage media might cause this. Low quality SD card, by any chance?

Comment: It's a thought - but no, not particularly poor quality I don't think. I have had an engineer successfully copy the entire SD contents onto his laptop (so that I could try reproduce the issue) with no problem.  So on the surface it would seem that there's no physical issue, since it can all be read.

Comment: @Nik: But is it SD card IO that fails (or device flash memory)? If SD card, then check a failing card on the desktop using the Error-Checking tools available for drives by right-clicking one in the Explorer and choosing Properties. Been there, seen that problem.

Comment: Yes - is an SD card. Thanks - I'll try get an engineer out to do just that.  But do you think its possible that the SD card is perfectly readable by a laptop though, throwing no errors, but not so by the device?

Comment: @Nik: Yes. I find device IO to be more sensitive to subtle disk errors.

Comment: Just spoke to person that did the copying, and it was actually copied using the device itself, onto a usb stick plugged into the device - so the device did indeed do all the reading.  Bit I will be running the check anyway as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks Johann - was indeed the case.  Interestingly, the WinCE scandisk wouldn't completely fix it - had to resort to Windows version.

Comment: @Nik: I've found SanDisk consistently more reliable than, for instance, Kingston. But, as always, YMMV.